# mysqldump a database with condition on tables

Tags: mysql

My MySQL database has tables which contain the column `company_id` and other tables don't, and I want to dump all the data into a SQL file.

But I need to add a `where company_id=1` only for the tables that have this column, and for the rest I need to get all the data.

This is not working for me because I have to specify the table name, and what I need is to dump everything with a the condition on every table that has that column :

`mysqldump -u root -p root databaseName tableName --where company_id=1 > mydb_tables.sql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it with the combination of --tables option of mysqldump?
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-filter-options

You'll have to modify your mysqldump command each time you have more/less tables with that column name though.

Edit:
You can try specifying the table names after the database name too, --tables is not really needed then.

> Normally, mysqldump treats the first name argument on the command line
>   as a database name and following names as table names.

Edit 2:
I just tested this dumping multiple tables and their rows where "id=1", so it must be working if you just specify all your tables with column company_id.
You'll need one command to dump all tables with that column, and one command for all other tables (maybe use --ignore-table would come in handy here).

Comment: So I need two `mysqldump ` commands, first will do the `where company_id=1` on the tables that I specified and know that they have the column, and the second will be on the rest, and I'll end up with 2 dump files ?